# Relative layout doesnot take full screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In my application I want the `RelativeLayout` to cover the whole screen. But when I run my application the height is lesser than screen height.

Screen dimension: 720x1280
RelativeLayout dimensions: 720x1230

Here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    tools:context="com.selfie.app.MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/opaque"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/timeranim"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="38dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="invisible" />


    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/captureImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/cameraanim" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/flash"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/captureImage"
        android:background="@drawable/flashanim" 
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/flipCamera"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/captureImage"
        android:background="@drawable/camera" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: chnage this `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to match parent in ur root layout

Comment: match parent does not work as well

Comment: what does match parent gives you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match_parent` and `fill_parent` does the same thing. Maybe you should notice the `RelativeLayout`'s parent.

Have a try to request `Windows.FEATURE_NO_TITLE` before `setContentView`;